# React Native - Start Google Maps Navigation in custom application

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, react-native

I am working on a react native application and I am able to open Google maps navigation/assistant. I have the following code to open navigation mode in Google Maps app.

```
function getDirections ({ destination, source, params = [] } = {}) {
    if (destination && isValidCoordinates(destination)) {
        params.push({
            key: 'destination',
            value: `${destination.latitude},${destination.longitude}`
        })
    }
    if (source && isValidCoordinates(source)) {
        params.push({
            key: 'origin',
            value: `${source.latitude},${source.longitude}`
        })
    }

    const url = `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&${getParameterString(params)}`
    return Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
        if (!supported) {
            return Promise.reject(new Error(`Could not open the url: ${url}`))
        } else {
            return Linking.openURL(url)
        }
    })
}
```

I am looking to open navigation view in my application instead of Google maps. I have the maps component. Is it possible?

Comment: This article might help, https://medium.com/@princessjanf/react-native-maps-with-direction-from-current-location-ab1a371732c2